# Why django model save function does not respond?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to create a blog post model and I added a schedule filed on Django model that I can schedule my post by date and time if `schedule time == now`. Then post should be verified and display to dashboard so for this I used `def save` function. But `save` function does not respond. When I tried to schedule a blog post from admin panel it did not change `verified = True`. Here is code what I did so far:

```
from django.utils import timezone
now = timezone.now()  # get the current time


class Blog(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="post")
    title = models.CharField(_("Title of blog post"),
                             max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)
    header = models.CharField(
        _("Blog title eg. TIPS, "), max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(_("Slug of the title"), max_length=250,
                            unique_for_date='publish', null=True, blank=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(_("Blog post main image"), default="img.png",
                              null=True, blank=True, upload_to='users/avatar')
    read_time = models.TimeField(
        _("Blog post read time"), null=True, blank=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, verbose_name=_(
        "Blog category list"), on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    publish = models.DateField()
    tags = TaggableManager(blank=True)
    description = HTMLField()
    views = models.IntegerField(default="0")  # <- here
    verified = models.BooleanField(
        _("Approved post before push on production"), default=False)
    schedule = models.DateTimeField(
        _("Schedule post by date and time"), auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, null=True, blank=True)


    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('blog')
        verbose_name_plural = _('blogs')


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.schedule >= now:
            self.verified = True
            print(self.verified)
        else:
            self.slug = slugify(self.title) # this also not respond
        super(Blog, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Exactly why do you expect it to verify? The odds of the `self.schedule` being now is (nearly) zero, since that should mean it has the same number of "tick"s.

Comment: i want that if schedule  date time is over then post should be verified change to `True` @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: just make an annotation, or a property that is true if `scheduled` is less than or equal to `Now()`.

Comment: i am getting error '<=' not supported between instances of 'datetime.datetime' and 'function' like this @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: because `now` is a function, so it should be `now()`, but that will not fix it (effectively).

Answer (score 0):

what is now ? I don't see it defined. I think that the correct way to do it is

from django.utils.timezone import now

if self.schedule <= now():
   do it

Comment: i am getting error `'<=' not supported between instances of 'datetime.datetime' and 'function'` like this @OlivierAudry

Answer (score 0):

The `save()` function is only called when you *save* an object. This thus means that although an object has a `self.schedule` that is already passed the current timestamp, one should wait until the object is saved again (and that can take a long time).

It is better to *annotate* the queryset with a field that specifies that it is `verified` when `self.scheduled` is less than (or equal to) `Now()`. We thus can define a manager that injects the annotation, and remove the `verified` field:

```
from django.db.models import BooleanField, ExpressionWrapper, Q
from django.db.models.functions import Now

class BlogManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs).annotate(
            verified=ExpressionWrapper(Q(scheduled__lte=Now()), BooleanField())
        )

class Blog(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="post")
    title = models.CharField(_("Title of blog post"),
                             max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)
    header = models.CharField(
        _("Blog title eg. TIPS, "), max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(_("Slug of the title"), max_length=250,
                            unique_for_date='publish', null=True, blank=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(_("Blog post main image"), default="img.png",
                              null=True, blank=True, upload_to='users/avatar')
    read_time = models.TimeField(
        _("Blog post read time"), null=True, blank=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, verbose_name=_(
        "Blog category list"), on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    publish = models.DateField()
    tags = TaggableManager(blank=True)
    description = HTMLField()
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    schedule = models.DateTimeField(
        _("Schedule post by date and time"), auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, null=True, blank=True)

    objects = BlogManager()
```

Comment: i am getting error `Manager isn't accessible via Blog instances` @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: @Piotr: it is indeed not accessible via *instances*, you should access it through the class, not through objects of that class. But that normally does not work with the original manager either.